# R: Subset from two data frames based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, conditional-statements, statements

I have two dataframes (df1 and df2), and I want a new dataframe (df3) containing all rows where "date" AND "time_of_day" of df1 match with df2. And save the rows of df1 that don't match as well in a new dataframe (df4).

I tried using dplyr filter function, but it seems like I am not writing it correctly, as I am getting a new dataframe of the same length as df1 but it should show me only the matching rows based on both variables date and time of day.

```
> df1
          date time_of_day     
1  2018-06-03     morning 
2  2018-06-06     afternoon 
4  2018-06-09     morning 
5  2018-06-10     afternoon 

> df2
          date time_of_day     
1  2018-06-03     morning 
2  2018-06-06     morning 
3  2018-06-08     morning 
4  2018-06-09     morning 
5  2018-06-10     afternoon
6  2018-06-11     afternoon

#creating a new data frame
df3 <- filter(df1, date %in% df2$date & time_of_day %in% df2$time_of_day)
#another try 
df3 <- df1[df1$date %in% df2$date & df1$time_of_day %in% df2$time_of_day,]
```

This is what I want:

```
> df3
          date time_of_day     
1  2018-06-03     morning 
2  2018-06-09     morning 
3  2018-06-10     afternoon 

> df4
          date time_of_day     
1  2018-06-06     afternoon
```

Comment: Try `inner_join(df1, df2)` and `anti_join(df1, df2)`

Answer (score 3):

We can do this with `inner_join`

```
library(dplyr)
df3 <- inner_join(df1, df2)
df3
#       date time_of_day
#1 2018-06-03     morning
#2 2018-06-09     morning
#3 2018-06-10   afternoon
```

and `anti_join`

```
df4 <- anti_join(df1, df2)
df4
#       date time_of_day
#1 2018-06-06   afternoon
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(date = c("2018-06-03", "2018-06-06", "2018-06-09", 
"2018-06-10"), time_of_day = c("morning", "afternoon", "morning", 
"afternoon")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"4", "5"))

df2 <- structure(list(date = c("2018-06-03", "2018-06-06", "2018-06-08", 
"2018-06-09", "2018-06-10", "2018-06-11"), time_of_day = c("morning", 
"morning", "morning", "morning", "afternoon", "afternoon")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: thank you so much, I think that is going to help, the only problem I have now, is that in my real df2 are more columns than in df1, so I don't achieve the result that I need. Do you know how I can solve that?

Comment: @chiarasahara  Just subset the columns of 'df2' i.e. only use the columns to join `inner_join(df1, df2[c("date", "time_of_day")])`

Comment: I can't really seem to get the same output with my real data. The structure is the same. But in my df3 are all dates in double or triple version now. You have an idea why?

Comment: @chiarasahara  Please check if there are dupes in both datasets for the joining columns.  In that case, it would make the program difficult to know which row to match resulting in duplicate matches

Comment: yes in the df2 are often more than one possibility for the same date unfortunately

Comment: @chiarasahara  In that case,  you may need to take a decision on which row to match.  You can use `distinct` to get the distinct rows where it keeps the first row and remove the duplicate, ie. `distinct(df2[c("date", "time_of_day")])` and then do the join.  But, the decision depends on your problem, and the logic you want to implement

Comment: wow, now I get my result, thank you so much for your patience :) you made my day!

Answer (score 2):

Altering your base R code, you could do this (below). And you can wrap either in `unique()` if you want duplicate rows removed.

```
df1[paste0(df1$date, df1$time_of_day) %in% paste0(df2$date, df2$time_of_day), ]
        date time_of_day
1 2018-06-03     morning
4 2018-06-09     morning
5 2018-06-10   afternoon
```

and

```
df1[!paste0(df1$date, df1$time_of_day) %in% paste0(df2$date, df2$time_of_day), ]
        date time_of_day
2 2018-06-06   afternoon
```

Your attempts before did not work because `df1$date %in% df2$date & df1$time_of_day %in% df2$time_of_day` evaluates to `TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE`. So it retained all rows. That is to say: all dates in `df1` are in `df2` & all times of day in `df1` are in `df2`.

EDIT:

Alternatively, in `dplyr` you could use `intersect` and `setdiff` which work with dataframes and remove duplicates:

```
dplyr::intersect(df1, df2)
        date time_of_day
1 2018-06-03     morning
2 2018-06-09     morning
3 2018-06-10   afternoon

dplyr::setdiff(df1, df2)
        date time_of_day
1 2018-06-06   afternoon
```